# ExpressJS: app.get()/app.set() data lifetime

Tags: node.js, express

In express.js we can use app.set/get to obtain variables across a request, print them in a jade view and access them in an advanced stage middleware.

But - I can't find in express's documentation what is the lifetime of these variables.

For example if I use:

```
app.set('my-var', 'here is my var');
```

And trying to pull it in the same middleware chain:

```
console.log(app.get('my-var')); // would work
```

But on a new request middleware chain I get `undefined`

Can I get a clearance?

Comment: I think there is no lifetime for this settings, because when you run your application it will be set and visible from places where you have access to your app variable using `app.get`.

Comment: Works for me. `console.log(app.get('my-var'))` outputs the expected value from request handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as no one will not overwrite it, source from `express/lib/application.js`

**app.init()** - bootsrapp ExpressJS

```
this.settings = {};
```

default configuration - assing settings to locals

```
this.locals.settings = this.settings;
```

**app.set()** - method definition

```
app.set = function(setting, val){   
  // set value
  this.settings[setting] = val;
```

**app.render()** - it is time to render view

```
app.render = function(name, options, fn){
  var opts = {};
  var view;

  // merge app.locals
  merge(opts, this.locals);

  // merge options._locals
  if (options._locals) {
    merge(opts, options._locals);
  }

  // merge options
  merge(opts, options);

  // render
  try {
    view.render(opts, fn);
  } catch (err) {
    fn(err);
  }
}
```

there is no magic in **ExpressJS** - settings and local.settings are merged before render. The are no methods like - clear settings, clear locals. Whatever is set it will be avaible.

Comment: Downvoted because this does not answer the question, or at least it's very unclear if it does.